# IPSocket ruby NameError error?

Tags: ruby

When using IRB with input, getting error:

```
IPSocket.getaddress("localhost")
```

Error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant IPSocket
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add top before using the class :

```
require 'socket'
```

See this [`socket/ipsocket.c`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/socket/rdoc/IPSocket.html).

Example :-

```
2.1.0 :022 > require 'socket'
 => true 
2.1.0 :023 > IPSocket.getaddress("localhost")
 => "::1" 
2.1.0 :024 >
```

Comment: why cant I get my ip addres but instead getting #=> "::1" ? Whats the difference?

Comment: @user3222947 Please follow this [post](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4708150#new) to get your answer. It's a bit weird. As  this was not your primary question, you can close this now by accepting my answer.